# Hot/cold water issues while showering

Tags: plumbing

I have periodic hot/cold water issues while showering & my landlord is giving me a hard time about solving it. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe nothing. Have you determined the cause? Are you in a multi-use building, or, is anyone else using water when you have this issue? If 100% no, then, what kind of water supply is used, city, well, etc..., what area on the planet do you live? What is used to heat the water? Is the problem always there from the start of the shower? When was the thing that heats the water installed (often is labeled on it). Answer these and maybe we can suggest an approach.

Comment: Start looking for a new place to rent from a different landlord, all too often is the only answer that really works, unless you can afford to buy a place and then it becomes your problem to get such problems fixed...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Agreed @DanielGriscom, if the question is simply "how do I get my landlord to do what I want" it's off topic. While we can possibly advise how to pinpoint a cause, I'm voting to close it as off topic because even if we are heading down the path of home improvement, a renter is properly powerless to fix it.

Comment: Join a fitness club with showers?

Comment: Your water supplier could be experiencing periodic pressure drops; you would have to contact your water supply company. If you're in a multi-tenant apartment then other people might be using the water at the same time as you so that creates a natural drop in pressure; your only option is to shower at a different time or somehow convince your landlord to upgrade the pipe size in the building.